# Vectorizing numpy polyfit for moving window

Tags: python, numpy, polynomials

I'd like to vectorize following function

```
def nppolyfit(pnp_array, **kwargs):
  """ Moving polyfit 
  """
  win_size = kwargs['length']
  degree = kwargs['degree']

  xdata = range(win_size)
  res = np.zeros(pnp_array.shape)

  for i in range(win_size, len(pnp_array) + 1):
      res[i-1]  = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(xdata , pnp_array[i - win_size : i], deg = degree))(win_size)

  return res
```

What was done so far:

```
def rolling_window(a, window):
    shp = a.shape[:-1] + (a.shape[-1] - window + 1, window)
    strides = a.strides + (a.strides[-1],)
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=shp, strides=strides)

def nppolyfitv(pnp_array, **kwargs):
  """ Moving polyfit 
  """
  win_size = kwargs['length']
  degree = kwargs['degree']

  xdata = np.arange(win_size)
  ydata = rolling_window(pnp_array, win_size).T
  fit = np.polyfit(xdata, ydata, deg = degree)
  res = np.zeros(len(pnp_array))
  res[win_size-1:] = np.polynomial.polynomial.polyval(np.zeros(len(pnp_array)), fit).T[len(pnp_array) - 1,:]

  return res
```

But it looks like I am missing something or doing wrong. Could you please correct me? Maybe there is another more effective solution? Thanks.

Test case:

```
import numpy as np
npd = np.arange(30)
win_size1 = 11
degree = 1
c1  =     nppolyfit(npd, length=win_size1, degree=degree)
c1v  =   nppolyfitv(npd, length=win_size1, degree=degree)
print(c1)
print(c1v)
```

And results are:

```
[  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.  11.  12.  13.  14.  15.
  16.  17.  18.  19.  20.  21.  22.  23.  24.  25.  26.  27.  28.  29.  30.]
[   0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    1.   30.
   59.   88.  117.  146.  175.  204.  233.  262.  291.  320.  349.  378.
  407.  436.  465.  494.  523.  552.]
```

Comment: A good SO question shows what works or doesn't work - errors, tracebacks, right and wrong results.  We don't like setting up our own test cases even if the functions are clear.

Comment: I am trying to compare results from both functions. But second one returns not what is expected. And for now I can't understand why.

Comment: I deduced that much from the original question.  But without copying the code to my own session, defining some sort of test data (guessing at what you might use), I can't guess what's different.  Most of us, unless we had recently worked with a similar task, can't just read code and diagnose differences.  We have to use the conventional debugging steps of testing and printing intermediate results.

Comment: Added test case and its results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`polyfit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html) method returns polynomial coefficients, **highest powers first**.

The [`polyval`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyval.html) method expects the coefficients to have **lowest powers first**. Take this into account when feeding the output of one method to another.

Also, the x-argument of `polyval` is illogical: `np.zeros(len(pnp_array))`. Why do you ask `polyval` to evaluate the polynomial at the same point 0, many times? Especially since your non-vectorized function evaluated the polynomial at `win_size`. To be consistent with the non-vectorized method, replace the line

```
res[win_size-1:] = np.polynomial.polynomial.polyval(np.zeros(len(pnp_array)), fit).T[len(pnp_array) - 1,:]
```

with

```
res[win_size-1:] = np.polynomial.polynomial.polyval(win_size, fit[::-1])
```

then both outputs for the test case are the same.

(That said, I also don't know why you evaluate the polynomial at the right edge of the window; would the middle be the more representative value? But that is something for you to decide.)

Comment: I am a little bit confused with indexes and arguments. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to compare intermediate values of the two methods;

For example I can track the `polyfit` step with

```
In [304]: def nppolyfit(pnp_array, **kwargs):
     ...:   """ Moving polyfit 
     ...:   """
     ...:   win_size = kwargs['length']
     ...:   degree = kwargs['degree']
     ...: 
     ...:   xdata = np.arange(win_size)
     ...:   res = np.zeros(pnp_array.shape)
     ...:   fits = []
     ...:   for i in range(win_size, len(pnp_array) + 1):
     ...:       fit = np.polyfit(xdata , pnp_array[i - win_size : i], deg = degr
     ...: ee)
     ...:       res[i-1] = np.poly1d(fit)(win_size)
     ...:       fits.append(fit)
     ...:   return res, fits
     ...: 
     ...: 
In [305]: 
In [305]: nppolyfit(npd,length=win_size1, degree=degree)
Out[305]: 
(array([  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,  11.,
         12.,  13.,  14.,  15.,  16.,  17.,  18.,  19.,  20.,  21.,  22.,
         23.,  24.,  25.,  26.,  27.,  28.,  29.,  30.]),
 [array([  1.00000000e+00,   1.60677522e-15]),
  array([ 1.,  1.]),
  array([ 1.,  2.]),
  array([ 1.,  3.]),
  array([ 1.,  4.]),
  array([ 1.,  5.]),
  array([ 1.,  6.]),
  array([ 1.,  7.]),
  array([ 1.,  8.]),
  array([ 1.,  9.]),
  array([ 1., 10.]),
  array([  1.,  11.]),
  array([  1.,  12.]),
  array([  1.,  13.]),
  array([  1.,  14.]),
  array([  1.,  15.]),
  array([  1.,  16.]),
  array([  1.,  17.]),
  array([  1.,  18.]),
  array([  1.,  19.])])
```

I should then compare that with the `fit` variable in the multidimensional polyfit case.

Changing your last function to return `fit` as well as `res`:

```
In [308]: nppolyfitv(npd, length=win_size1, degree=degree)
Out[308]: 
(array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
         1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
         1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]),
 array([[  1.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,
           1.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,
           1.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,
           1.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,
           1.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,
           1.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,
           1.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00],
        [  1.60677522e-15,   1.00000000e+00,   2.00000000e+00,
           3.00000000e+00,   4.00000000e+00,   5.00000000e+00,
           6.00000000e+00,   7.00000000e+00,   8.00000000e+00,
           9.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+01,   1.10000000e+01,
           1.20000000e+01,   1.30000000e+01,   1.40000000e+01,
           1.50000000e+01,   1.60000000e+01,   1.70000000e+01,
           1.80000000e+01,   1.90000000e+01]]))
```

Fits appear to match.  So presumably the problem is with the `poly1d` step.